# splitting the string in bash script

Tags: bash, shell-script, filenames, string

I am taking some input from user and checking details about that.

Example:

```
$HOME/Documents/test/one.txt
```

I take the above string as an input and want to retrieve `one.txt`, I need to further proceed with `one.txt`.

Comment: You really should just ask your real question.

Comment: @bahamat I want to get one.txt from input.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

@Jordanm has already given you the canonical answer that works for any string. If you are dealing specifically with paths, you can also use the programs `basename` and `dirname`:

```
   basename - strip directory and suffix from filenames
   dirname - strip last component from file name
```

For example:

```
$ file="$HOME/Documents/test/one.txt"
$ dir=$(dirname "$file");
$ name=$(basename "$file");
$ echo "The file called $name is in the directory $dir"
The file called one.txt is in the directory /home/terdon/Documents/test
```

Answer (score 5):

This is a common task that can be handled by a [parameter expansion](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/073) in any POSIX shell.

```
path=$HOME/Documents/test/one.txt
file=${path##*/} # file contains one.txt
```

Another common method is to use the basename program.

```
file=$(basename "$path")
```

The only disadvantage is having to spawn an external program. It's main advantage is that it properly handles paths with a trailing `/`.

Comment: To be pedantic, `"$(basename "$path")"` is wrong in the unlikely event that `$path` ends with a newline. This is because a) `basename` adds an extra newline on the end, and b) `$(command)` strips all trailing newlines. To make it work requires a perverse workaround, something like this: `path=$'/tmp/evil\n'; file="$(basename "$path"; printf x)"; strip=$'\nx'; fixed="${file%%$strip}"`

Answer (score 1):

If you're doing this with filenames, use the `basename` command:

```
$ basename $HOME/Documents/test/one.txt
one.txt
```

Further:

```
$ FILE=$(basename basename $HOME/Documents/test/one.txt)
$ echo $FILE
one.txt
```

If you need to split arbitrary strings with arbitrary delimiters it's a little bit of magic. Read the string into an array and set the input field separator to the delimiter.

Here's an example:

```
$ IFS='/' read -a my_array <<< "$HOME/Documents/test/one.txt"
$ ARRAY_LENGTH=$(( ${#my_array[@]} - 1 ))
$ echo "${my_array[$ARRAY_LENGTH]}"
one.txt
```